# Declaring a jagged array in C#

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I have a data in a following format:

`{{{0}},{{1}},{{2,3}},{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8},{9,10}},....`
Is there any way of storing this in a jagged array? The data is large, and I would like to include it directly in the code. I searched internet and it says I can declare it in a following way:

```
{ new int[][] { new int[] {0} }, new int[][] { new int[] {1} }, 
    new int[][] { new int[] {2,3} }, new int[][] {new int[] {1,2} ,new int[] {3,4} } , ...
```

but typing those new `int[][]` would be too time consuming and I am looking for a way that I can used the original data directly into the code.
Is there a way to do that?
Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: I would be grateful if you can read up about the mark up and format the question so that it is readable. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. Actually I am trying to make a windows forms application, in that case will the tag c# be appropriate?

Comment: Depends on the programming language you wish to employ

Comment: Well, tag it as C#, rather than wasting time of people who know C or C++ but not C#.    The `new int` etc approach you have is not valid in C++ either.      In C++, there is no direct way to do what you ask in a single declaration or statement, anyway.

Comment: Have you considered using loops?

Comment: Everybody considers using loops. How exactly should I use loops?

Comment: Is the depth of nesting limited to three or does it keep going on? The a tree structure might be better. What do the data describe?

Comment: Loops to initialize the arrays. You really should store this kind of stuff in a file or a database instead of in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your primary objective is to incorporate existing data into your code as an initialized c# jagged array, I suggest the following:

1. Paste the existing data.
2. Search and replace `{` with `new [] {`, except for the very first occurrence.
3. Assign to a variable with type `int[][][]` (add additional `[]`s if more than three levels).

Formatted for readability, the result should be a valid c# statement as follows:

```
int[][][] x =
{
    new[] {
        new[] {0}
    },
    new[] {
        new[] {1}
    },
    new[] {
        new[] {2,3},
        new[] {2,3}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx), I think you can use mix jagged and multidimensional arrays to make it a little easier.

```
        int[][,] test = new int[][,] {
            new int[,] { { 0 } },
            new int[,] { { 1 } },
            new int[,] { { 2, 3 } },
            new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }
        };
```